# Login as Popup in index.php - how can I use session variables after loggin in in index.php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, session-variables

I have a problem. I integrated the login formular in index.php as a pop-up. After submitting login.php is required where the input values get controlled, whether they are correct. If these values are correct some data of the database get selected. How can I use these data? I cant get nor echo the session variables after logging in, somehow. What needs to be fixed/added? I tried to refresh index.php after logging in but nothing happens. For testing purpose I want the $firstname variable to be displayed in the body of index.php after logging in. How can I achieve that?

Code-Snippet of index.php

```
<?php 
ob_start();
require 'db.php';
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Popup</title>
<?php include 'css/css.html';?>
</head>

<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) { //user logging in
        require 'login.php';
    }
    elseif (isset($_POST['register'])) { //user registering
        require 'register.php';
    }
}
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
$email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ){ // User doesn't exist
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Kein Nutzer mit dieser E-Mail-Adresse existiert!";
    header("location: error.php");
}
else { // User exists
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if ( password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password']) ) {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $user['first_name'];
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = $user['last_name'];
        $_SESSION['active'] = $user['active'];

        // Logged in?
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        header('refresh:1; url=index.php');
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Falsches Passwort: versuche es erneut!";
        header("location: error.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.